# Calling hook_entity_view from a theme

Tags: 7, hooks, theming, entities

Is there any way to call `hook_entity_view()` from a theme?

I tried adding the implementation to the `template.php` file, but the function is not called.

I know I can do it via custom module, but as it's a rather UI addition, it would make more sense to do through theme.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hook_entity_view()` will only be invoked for modules so no chance of putting it in a theme unless you want to change how something works under the hood.

It's not a problem though, as all alter hooks *are* invoked for themes; so you can use [`hook_entity_view_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_view_alter/7) instead.

> This hook is called after the content has been assembled in a structured array and may be used for doing processing which requires that the complete entity content structure has been built.